# Creating a DF Column from an initial value

Tags: python

I am new to Python, I wonder how to programmatically create a new column in a DF starting with an initial value in row 0 and then for each subsequent row you add the previous row +  a fixed delta.

[5,5+2,7+2,9+2,...,X(n-1)+2]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what you have tried so far. Read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: Take a look at [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) it takes a start value and a step and creates an infinite iterator. Then you just take how many elements you need...